# Android Studio issue ,kt files appears in unkown form?

Tags: android, kotlin

My code is code and already publish it

when i try to make some updates with Android studio 3.3.RC3 + 1.3.20 Kotlin

i face this problem Kt files appears as XML or unknown code

[image: screen for my problem]

I try to update Android studio 3.3.2 + 1.3.20 Kotlin

and the problem stile appears

I ask why there is problems with update in Android Studio

I think it must be the strong platform with Android development

as Google its backed ???

Comment: i can't say why you are facing this problem . but you can check history for that file and see all modification

Comment: Are you sure that `Computer.kt` contain Kotlin code? Maybe somebody paste there some xml (e.g. by mistake)?

Comment: @Tejas Pandya,I am sure this problem from Android studio or kotlin plugin ,but why it happen and ho i can solve it.

Comment: @Boken,yes i am sure ,,my app was published and I return to my code to do some updates. All other kt files as the same unknown code ,i display this file as example.